# Solutions to $\varphi''(z)+\frac{2\varphi'(z)}z+\varphi(z)^n=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this equation for n = 0, n = 1 nad n = 5
$$\frac{d^2 \varphi}{dz^2}+\frac{2}{z}\frac{d\varphi}{dz} + \varphi^n = 0$$

I don't know what to do with z in a position of coefficient.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that this differential equation has a nice solution?

Comment: There seems to be a nice solution for [$n = 0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27+%2B+2y%27%2Fx+%2B+1+%3D+0) and [$n = 1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27+%2B+2y%27%2Fx+%2B+y+%3D+0), but it's not clear that this is the case for $n=5$.

Comment: One could also look under the name "Lane-Emden equation", usually written as $z^{-2}(z^2φ')'=-φ^n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n=0$ then the equation is $$\varphi''(z)+\frac{2\varphi'(z)}z=-1.$$ Making the obvious substitution $f(z)=\varphi'(z)$ we obtain the first-order ODE $$f'(z)+\frac{2 f(z)}z=-1.$$ Using the [standard procedure for first-order equations with variable coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First-order_equation_with_variable_coefficients), we obtain $$f(z)=\frac{C}{z^2}-\frac z3$$ for an arbitrary constant $C$ from which we can obtain $\phi$.

If $n=1$, we want to eliminate the first-order term with the substitution $\varphi(z)=\frac{\nu(z)}z$. This leads to $$\nu''(z)+\nu(z)=0.$$ I hope you can finish it off now.

If $n=5$ then I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Thank you  very much and how you get the form after substitution?

Answer (score 0):

For $n=5$ there's a general solution of this form:

$$ F(\sqrt{z} \varphi(z)) = a \pm \ln(z)/6$$
where $F(t)$ is an antiderivative of $1/\sqrt{b + 9 t^2 - 12 t^6}$ ($a$ and $b$ are arbitrary constants).